# State rendering issue, is this the right pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, hydration

So I have this kind of issue, having a React Context where I manage authentication I use a protected routes component to disable accessing pages when the user is not authenticated (no localstorage user data available).

But there is a problem with this approach, because at the first pre-render the user is undefined (`useState()`) and only after useEffect runs the user data is fetched.

Snippet code:

AuthContextProvider

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [hydrated, setHydrated] = useState(false); // added to fix the problem

  useEffect(() => {
    const userLocal = localStorage.getItem('user');
    setUser(JSON.parse(userLocal));
    setHydrated(true); // added to fix the problem
  }, []);
```

Protected routes:

```
  if (isBrowser() && !authCtx.user && pathIsProtected) {
    router.push('/signin');
  }
```

So I end up having user = undefined for a fraction of second that is enough to catch the condition `!authCtx.user`, instead the user is authenticated.

As you can see in the code my workaround that works is to use a `hydrated` variable which I set together with the user data from localstorage and in the provider I wait the hydrated variable to be true before rendering the children components (where the protected route is)

```
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        error: error,
        loading: loading,
        user: user
      }}
    >
      {hydrated && children} {/* added to fix the problem */}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

This way everything works fine but is this the right pattern for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, which is almost the same but uses `user` variable instead of `hydrated`:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
```

And in the component:

```
  ...
  >
    {user && children} {/* added to fix the problem */}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
  ...
```

This way you can drop `const [hydrated, setHydrated] = useState(false);` altogether.

Comment: Ouch! You are right!